# In kettle what is output field in java script and how to use setVariable in it

Tags: pentaho

In kettle what is output field in java script and how to use setVariable in it.I tried to set variable in it but it gave me error

Comment: Please provide an example of your transformation. I'm not sure what you are referring with variables, but if you are talking about transformation variables, note that they cannot be reused in the same transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript step takes the input from the previous steps and can be accessed from the input field. If you want to pass the same field to the output, you need to us the output field.

Also if you want to set the variable in javascript step, you can use

```
setVariable("variablename","value","type");
```

Answer (score 0):

they are two different things. 
the javascript if connected in a stream , gets as input all the fields (columns) 
and can manipulate them with regular javascript.

if you want a new variable that will be a part of the stream all you need to do is:
var X;

then you can write this X as output at the bottom of the step. 
give it a name and use it

so if you use something like
x = fieldA + fieldB 
you can use the x on the stream.

the set variables used for setting a variable in one job to use in another job
its more like global / public in programming.

if you want to learn more about it you can take my course 
just click [pentaho kettle tutorial](http://pentahokettletutorial.com)  there is a lesson (video) on both steps